# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Cree una funcion para poder mostrar datos aleatorios de una api pero al momento de tratar de mostrar estos datos me sale el siguiente error. Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON.

```
export default function Api() {
  
const [user , setUser] = useState('Username...')
  
  function jokeApi() {
  /*api url*/
  const url = ("/api/users/random_user");

  fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => setUser(data.username))
  }
  
  return (
  <main>
  <button onClick={jokeApi}>New User</button>
  <p>{user}</p>
  </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: El mensaje de error está siendo descriptivo: "Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON.". ¿La API está retornando un mensaje de error como html?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.